# Can not get updated value of Parent class from op() method of child class Add

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I also tried this code from python latest version and 3.11.2. I want to get the result like below:

```
Arithmetic Operation Start 20 + 25
Now Addition Start
10 + 15 = 25
20 + 25 = 45
```

But I got result like below:

```
Arithmetic Operation Start 20 + 25
Now Addition Start
10 + 15 = 25
0 + 0 = 0
```

Full Code is given below:

```
class Parent:
    a = 0
    b = 0

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a + 10
        self.b = b + 10
        print(f"Arithmetic Operation Start {self.a} + {self.b}")

class Add(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a, b)  # Call parent constructor with updated values of a and b
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        print("Now Addition Start")

    def op(self):
        print(f"{self.a} + {self.b} = {self.a+self.b}")
        print(f"{super().a} + {super().b} = {super().a+super().b}")

s1 = Add(10, 15)
s1.op()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have three namespaces here:

1. Instance's namespace
2. `Add`'s namespace
3. `Parent`'s namespace

(for the rest of the answer I'm only gonna talk about `a`)

Before instantiation, only the `Parent`'s namespace has `a` which is `0`. Now let's go through the code step by step.

In `Add(10, 15)`, the `__init__` of `Add` is called which in turn calls the `__init__` of the `Parent` using `super()`.

The point is even when `__init__` of the `Parent` is executing, that `self` points to the `s1` which is an instance of `Add`. (you can confirm it by `print(self)` there.

So now after executing `self.a = a + 10` line, you have `a = 20` in your **Instance's** namespace. What about the others?

```
Instance's namespace  --> {'a': 20}
`Add`'s namespace     --> {}
`Parent`'s namespace  --> {'a': 0}
```

Next, in the line `self.a = a`, you again putting something to the "Instance's namespace" (`s1`). This is how python works. It passes the bound instance over the chain. Now what would be the `a` in this case?

```
Instance's namespace  --> {'a': 10}
`Add`'s namespace     --> {}
`Parent`'s namespace  --> {'a': 0}
```

Now if you print the `self.a` you'll get it from the instance. If you print `super().a` you'll get it from the `Parent` class.

Answer (score 1):

Since a and b are attributes of the Parent class, you need to change them during initialization, not attributes of the class instance.

```
class Parent:
    a = 0
    b = 0

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        Parent.a = a + 10
        Parent.b = b + 10
        print(f"Arithmetic Operation Start {Parent.a} + {Parent.b}")


class Add(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a, b)  # Call parent constructor with updated values of a and b
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        print("Now Addition Start")

    def op(self):
        print(f"{self.a} + {self.b} = {self.a + self.b}")
        print(f"{super().a} + {super().b} = {super().a+super().b}")


s1 = Add(10, 15)
s1.op()


---------------------

Arithmetic Operation Start 20 + 25
Now Addition Start
10 + 15 = 25
20 + 25 = 45
```